# How to inject custom content via Nginx?

Tags: nginx, code-injection

Is there a way to inject a few lines of script etc. for each served php/html/etc. page?
For example some custom javascript after  -tag?

I know, you should be able to use lua in nginx but is there a better solution?

I am running multiple different web application behind the nginx, so it feels proper way to do this. I don't have access source code for each application and maintaining those would be cumbersome.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I found the way to do this: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html

```
location / {
    sub_filter </head>
        '</head><script language="javascript" src="$script"></script>';
    sub_filter_once on;
}
```

Comment: IndexHeadInsert is used in Apache I am looking for a similar command in NGINX

Comment: Quick note, this module is not built by default (as the linked article states) so your install may not have it. You can see if you have it with: `nginx -V` which "will list all the configured modules" ([Source](http://serverfault.com/a/223526/138913)) and look for `--with-http_sub_module`.

Comment: If the content is *gzipped* the substitution won't work. For that, add `proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";`, which tells the backend that compression isn't allowed in a response.

Comment: But what if I want to inject `base` at the start of `head` and `head` can contain some attributes, which I don't know in advance?